# Python virtual environment is not working

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

**Scenario:**

I have a ubuntu system. I am running two apps on my system which are using different versions of Paramiko. Version '1.16.0' is installed globally while '1.12.4' is in virtual environment, 'venv'.

Actually, I am following the complete tutorial from 'http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=4342' to use Falcon API and extended this to extract information from the http request and forward the information to my customized class which further creates a ssh connection using Fabric. I created a virtual environment in PyCharm and set interpreter to venv/bin/python2.7. I ran my customized class for testing and it worked perfectly; showing me the version '1.12.4' from command 'paramiko.**version**'. But when I run my Uwsgi server, get a request, extract information and forward to my customized class, the command 'paramiko.**version**' shows version '1.16.0'. Strange! I can't figure out the reason.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you are in your virtualenv when executing your script, could you post pip freeze results.

Comment: yes i am sure. my pip freeze is => `cffi==1.5.2
cryptography==1.3.1
ecdsa==0.13
enum34==1.1.3
idna==2.1
ipaddress==1.0.16
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.0
paramiko==1.12.4
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycparser==2.14
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyOpenSSL==16.0.0
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.24.0
`

Comment: And my app is still using Paramiko version 1.16.0, which is a global package.

Comment: are you running it from terminal or from a ide?

Comment: Basically, from terminal. i tried it on Pycharm as well but I am sure did I configured right. I created a virtual environment and then created .pycharm-bash file with source path. I set the Pycharm's interpreter to virtualenv and still could get the desired output. RIGHT NOW I AM TRYING TO RUN MY APP FROM TERMINAL.